# How to use seperate training and test file for python machine learning?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I have to use machine learning in class where I have a training data set and a test data set, its very difficult for me as I don't come from a coding background and they told me before i chose it that the class would be suitable for people without much prior knowledge.

I have processed the training data into a csv file where the first column is the review and the second column is its sentiment in the form of 1 or 0

I have loaded the file and processed it like this:

```
def load_file():
with open('trainingdatafile.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    reader.next()
    data = []
    target = []
    for row in reader:
        # skip missing data
        if row[0] and row[1]:
            data.append(row[0])
            target.append(row[1])

    return data, target
```

And I have processed the data like this :

```
def preprocess():
    data, target = load_file()
    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary='true')
    data = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
    tfidf_data = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(data)

return tfidf_data
```

I have found a way to make it work where I split the training data up and use part of it to train and the rest to test like so:

```
def learn_model(data, target):
# preparing data for split validation. 60% training, 40% test
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data, target, test_size=.2,
                                                                                     random_state=1)
classifier = BernoulliNB().fit(data_train, target_train)
predicted = classifier.predict(data_test)
evaluate_model(target_test, predicted)
```

the rest of the code is here:

```
def evaluate_model(target_true, target_predicted):
print classification_report(target_true, target_predicted)
print "The accuracy score is {:.2%}".format(accuracy_score(target_true, target_predicted))

def main():
    data, target = load_file()
    tf_idf = preprocess()
    learn_model(tf_idf, target)
```

What would be the best way to adapt my code so that I can evaluate my test.csv file with the training data? I am really stuck with how to achieve what I want so any help would be really appreciated.